# NHibernate query performance with a large number of disjunctions and conjunctions

Tags: c#, sql, hibernate, nhibernate

I'm trying to apply a filter to data from an NHibernate session using disjunctions and conjunctions. I have implemented this as follows:

```
var disjunction = new Disjunction();
foreach (var entry in filterCriteria.SelectedCriteria)
{
     var conjunction = Restrictions.Conjunction();
     conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("SourceAccount", entry.SourceAccount));
     conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("SourceItemId", entry.SourceItemId));
     conjunction.Add(Restrictions.Eq("SourceProgram", entry.SourceProgram));
     disjunction.Add(conjunction);
}
criteria.Add(disjunction);
```

The problem is that there are a large number of combinations in the SelectedCriteria collection, resulting in a SQL query that features a *lot* of WHERE (SourceAccount = x1, SourceItemId = x2, SourceProgram = x3) OR (SourceAccount = y1, SourceAccount = y2, SourceAccount = y3) OR ... etc etc. Meaning that the performance of the query is awful.

My question is how does one more sanely apply a large number of disjunctions and conjunctions to an NHibernate query?

Comment: This sounds like more of a SQL question than an NHibernate question. If NHibernate were out of the picture, how would you tune the query?

Comment: As Andrew  mentioned this is more to do with how to optimize the query than to do with NHibernate, if you have really big query with a lot of parameters may be you should use a SP or  a view to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is more of a SQL query issue than an NHibernate one. I resolved it by improving the logic of the full query to minimise the number of disjunctions and conjunctions produced.